# What are the next 2 letters in the sequence: B, U, C, S, D, R, ?,?

Tags: sequence, letter-sequence

> B, U, C, S, D, R, ?, ?

The above sequence is provided and we should guess the next 2 letters. The next letter could possibly be E, but what about after that?

Comment: Where did you find this sequence?

Answer (score 10):

The next two letters in the sequence are

> G and Q.

Explanation:

> Note that all letters in the sequence contain at least one curved segment; so this appears to be a spin on the classic sequence of "letters which contain a curved segment when written in all-caps":
>  BCDGJOPQRSU
>  (as opposed to AEFHIKLMNTVWXYZ).

> The spin here is that the sequence alternates between ascending values (starting with the beginning, B, and going forwards) and descending values (starting from the end, U, and going backwards):

> Thus, B U C S D R  = B > C > D alternating with U > S > R

> So the sequence continues with G, followed by Q.